# Graphaware TimeTree returning 404 in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphaware

I'm trying to use TimeTree with Neo4j but when attempting to call the API service it returns a 404.

I did originally have the neo4j windows installer version installed, but I've uninstalled it and using the zip file version now (as I understand it isn't compatible with the installer). The version of neo4j I'm using is 2.3.2.

The files in my plugin folder are:

1. graphaware-server-community-all-2.3.2.37.jar
2. graphaware-timetree-2.3.2.37.24.jar

I have also unblocked the zip file before extracting.

Any ideas what I could do?

Thanks

Comment: what is your configuration for the timetree? also did you add the jaxrs line in neo4j-server.properties file ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen For fear of sounding ignorant, what configuration?Following the guide on [GitHub](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-timetree) it just says to drope the jar files in the `plugins` directory and then I will be able to start. What is the jaxrs line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found what the issue is (with @ChristopeWillemsen pointing me in the direction).

The instructions for setting up TimeTree assume you have the framework configured already (as it says just drop in the files and away you go). If you go to the [GrahpAware framework site](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) it mentions that you need to add:

`org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.graphaware.server=/graphaware` to the neo4j-server.properties` file.

Adding this to the file made it work.